# Android- Get hash code from server

Tags: android, post, connection

my app connected to the server , once the server receive the data , it will send a hash code as response ... my questions is how to get this hashcode ?

I use the following code to POST data :

```
 try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String postURL = "http://somepostaddress.com";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "kris"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "xyz"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            Log.i("RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL(url_str);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
```

This is what i did for GET, it should work for POST too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29), this returns the response as a `String`.

Comment: String hashCode = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

Comment: This assumes you return the hashcode, or whatever string it is, as plain text in your response.

Comment: Then you are missing something in your request, that is the response your web server is returning.